# modify javascript to find first letter in a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, charat

I know little about javascript. From what I can see, this shows a set of rows that contain a value (in this case, the author of a WP plugin).

What I'd like to do, instead of finding the `data-name` value in the row, is find if the first letter of this value is "A". And hopefully I should be able to work on the preceding code to get to this part... :)

Thanks so much.

```
<script>
    var authors = [];
    $('.pba-id').each(function () {
        var author = $(this).attr('data-author');
        if (-1 == $.inArray(author, authors))
            authors.push(author);
    });

    $.each(authors, function (i, author) {
        $select.append($('<option>').html(author));
    });

    $select.change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
            if ('__pba_none' == value) {
    $('#the-list tr').show();
            return;
    }

    $('#the-list tr').each(function(){
    var $row = $(this);
            if ($row.find('.pba-id[data-author="' + value + '"]').length)
            $row.show();
            else
            $row.hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]`**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector.

> *Selects elements that have the specified **attribute with a value beginning** exactly with a given string.*

```js
$('#the-list tr').each(function() {
  var value = "A";
  var $row = $(this);
  if ($row.find('.pba-id[data-name^="' + value + '"]').length) {
    //---------------------------^^^
    $row.show();
  } else {
    $row.hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: @glennnall – I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#the-list tr').each(function() {
  // var value = "any value" ;
  var $row = $(this);
  if ($row.find('.pba-id[data-name^="' + value[0] + '"]').length) {
    $row.show();
  } else {
    $row.hide();
  }
});
```